# Creating Token with Sanctum in Laravel 9 with no 'expires_at' column

Tags: laravel, authentication, token, sanctum

I installed Laravel 9 and Sanctum, made a migration and tried to create token with 'createToken' method from User class which extends from Authenticatable. It's all from Laravel and Sanctum instalation. I used code below.

```
createToken('secrettoken')->plainTextToken;
```

And I've got an error message:

```
"message": "SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'expires_at' in 'field list' (SQL: insert into `personal_access_tokens` (`name`, `token`, `abilities`, `expires_at`, `tokenable_id`, `tokenable_type`, `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (secrettoken, 4afa89fe2706656efae648c43c2a451b5b6d10be8b4e4558b6f9097706f814eb, [\"*\"], ?, 14, App\\Models\\User, 2022-08-02 19:30:00, 2022-08-02 19:30:00))
```

It seems 'createToken' method wants to fullfil an non-existing 'expires_at' column and doesn't have a value. This method has two arguments: name and abilitie (optional).

Did anyone has the same problem as me? Maybe I'm doing some wrong or using this method wrong.

Comment: Can you please provide migration's code of table?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I am using the Laravel Sanctum today, and got the same error.

Comment: It has to be a bug after the last update of laravel. Fix below is ok but bug is a still a bug.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I had the same issue today, I checked the `createToken` method located at `vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/HasApiTokens.php`. `Sanctum` package has added `expires_at` column in this method, but didn't add that column to the `tokens migration` file.
[image]
So, I just add the `expires_at` column to their migration file.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->morphs('tokenable');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
        $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
        // Add here
        $table->timestamp('expires_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

And it worked.

Comment: I suspected that but I wanted to sure if it's something only me or common problem.

Comment: May be we can report this? Did anyone know where to report this on laravel.com?

Comment: Somebody just made this and there is a Fix :)
https://github.com/laravel/sanctum/commit/861f834441aecdcb8050521e7e517062684f0977

Comment: @Sandowl yeah, but solved that bug in our projects, Laravel will surely fix that bug soon.

Comment: yeah, it solves :)

Answer (score 4):

At the time I'm writing this, Laravel 10 comes already with "expires_at" column included on personal_access_tokens migration file.

Setting an expiration time to that column is very easy.
"createToken" method is defined in this file:  /vendor/laravel/sanctum/src/HastApiTokens.php and receives 3 parameters:

- a name string
- an array with the abilities
- a DateTimeInterface type object with the expiration time

All one has to do to set those parameters when you invoke the createToken method.

An example setting a token to expire after 6 days:

```
$token = $user->createToken(
    $user->name.'_'.Carbon::now(), // The name of the token
    ['*'],                         // Whatever abilities you want
    Carbon::now()->addDays(6).     // The expiration date
)->plainTextToken;
```

It could be more explicit on the docs, but when it's not there, nothing better than check how things work under the hood.

Comment: ```now()->addDays(6)``` work too

Answer (score 0):

You should publish the Sanctum configuration and migration files using the below **vendor:publish** Artisan command. The sanctum configuration file will be placed in your application's config directory.

```
php artisan vendor:publish --provider="Laravel\Sanctum\SanctumServiceProvider"
```

Then use "`php artisan migrate`" to create migration table.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('personal_access_tokens', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->morphs('tokenable');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('token', 64)->unique();
        $table->text('abilities')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('last_used_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('expires_at')->nullable();
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}
```

For more information refer https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/sanctum#installation

Answer (score 0):

You already have the database, hence migrate or add the column "expires_at" with timestamp on the `personal_access_tokens` table

Comment: You also need to add colum "batch_uuid" column at activity_log table with type integer? for Laravel 10